# C++ 11 future_status::deferred not working

Tags: c++, multithreading, stl, c++11, future

```
#include <iostream>
#include <future>
#include <chrono>

using namespace std;
using namespace std::chrono;

int sampleFunction(int a)
{
    return a;
}

int main()
{
   future<int> f1=async(launch::deferred,sampleFunction,10);
   future_status statusF1=f1.wait_for(seconds(10));
   if(statusF1==future_status::ready)
        cout<<"Future is ready"<<endl;
   else if (statusF1==future_status::timeout)
        cout<<"Timeout occurred"<<endl;
   else if (statusF1==future_status::deferred)
        cout<<"Task is deferred"<<endl;
   cout<<"Value : "<<f1.get()<<endl;
}

Output -
Timeout occurred
Value : 10
```

In above example, I was expecting `future_status` to be `deferred` instead of `timeout`. `sampleFunction` has been launched as `launch::deferred`. Hence it will not be executed until `f1.get()` has been called. In such condition `wait_for` should have returned `future_status::deferred` and not `future_status::timeout`.

Appreciate if someone can help me understand this.
I am using g++ version 4.7.0 on fedora 17.

Comment: GCC and the supplied standard library does not fully implement all functionality of C++11 yet. See e.g. [here](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/manual/status.html) for the status of the library.

Comment: from the page quoted by Joachim: "Class template future: Partial: Timed waiting functions do not return future_status". says it all

Comment: Voting to close, as the issue has no resolution.

Comment: Your example throws exception 
```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::system_error'
  what():  Unknown error -1
```
on GCC 11.1,  But success runs on clang 12.0  with libc++

Answer (score 3):

GCC and the GNU STL have no support of the complete C++ 11.

Here you can check out the C++ 11 implementation status in GCC and GNU STL:

http://gcc.gnu.org/projects/cxx0x.html

http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/manual/status.html

Also, read this discussion thread: http://blog.gmane.org/gmane.comp.gcc.bugs/month=20120201