# std::future still deferred when using std::packaged_task (VS11)

Tags: c++, c++11, visual-studio-2012, future, packaged-task

It seems that unless you call `std::async` a `std::future` will never be set to any other state than `future_status::deferred` unless you call `get` or `wait` on the future. `wait_for` & `wait_until` will continue to not block and return `future_status::deferred` even if the task has already run and stored the result.

Here's an example:

```
#include <future>

void main()
{
    auto func = []() { return 5; };
    auto asyncFuture = std::async(std::launch::async, func);
    auto status = asyncFuture.wait_for(std::chrono::seconds(0));   // timeout (1)

    auto deferredFuture = std::async(std::launch::deferred, func);
    status = deferredFuture.wait_for(std::chrono::seconds(0));     // deferred (2)

    std::packaged_task<int()> task(func);
    auto packagedTaskFuture = task.get_future();
    status = packagedTaskFuture.wait_for(std::chrono::seconds(0)); // deferred (2)

    task();

    status = packagedTaskFuture.wait_for(std::chrono::seconds(0)); // deferred (2)
    packagedTaskFuture.wait();
    status = packagedTaskFuture.wait_for(std::chrono::seconds(0)); // ready (0)
}
```

I don't have the current C++11 standard, but the draft standard in 30.6.9 says that when a `packaged_task` is run it should store the result in the future's shared state. It's not very clear whether that includes setting the expected `wait_until`/`wait_for` behavior or not.

There were previously issues with VS11 behavior in this area with respect to `async` calls: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/hu/parallelcppnative/thread/4394f2c1-0404-40df-869b-f4fc36fc035c

Additionally it seems like other compilers have problems in this area: [C++ 11 future_status::deferred not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12137283/c-11-future-statusdeferred-not-working)

Anyone that may know the standard better: Is this expected behavior or is there an issue with the implemenation in VS11?

Updates: I somehow missed the report for this: http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/761829/c-11-unexpected-behavior-for-std-future-wait-for-and-std-packaged-task

Comment: Same deferred status is obtained unfortunately by using VS 11 - Update 1, when future is obtained from promise (it works with async). The issue was reported to them a while back ago but is still not functioning. It practically defeats the purpose of using std::future in many cases. Works with boost 1.51 at least.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is an issue with VS2012. It's not the only issue either --- their implementation of the C++11 thread library has several bugs. I wrote about a few [on my blog](http://www.justsoftwaresolutions.co.uk/news/just-thread-v1.8.0-released.html).

Comment: Thanks! I knew the VS11 C++11 STL support was not that great, but I didn't think it'd be completely unusable. Any comments on boost's implementation of these features (obviously not async or things that they haven't implemented yet)?

Comment: The boost implementation is generally sound, for the features that are implemented. There are a few bugs, but we're working on them, and Vicente is working on the missing C++11 features.

Comment: @AnthonyWilliams Thanks for boost support. It is something that can be relied on for this

Comment: Microsoft has made me quite sad with their broken promises. :'(